# Fourier transformed multiplication operator leaves $L^2([-C,C])$ invariant?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $C > 0$ be some constant and $L^2([-C,C])$ the square integrable functions on $[-C,C]$. Let $\delta > 0$ and let $M_{|\cdot |^\delta}$ denote the multiplication operator on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ defined by the given function, i.e. $M_{|\cdot |^\delta} \phi(x) = |x|^\delta \phi(x)$ with the usual domain $D(M_{|\cdot |^\delta}) = \{ \phi \in L^2(\mathbb R) \colon M_{|\cdot |^\delta} \phi \in L^2(\mathbb R) \}$. Let $\mathcal F$ be the Fourier transform.

Could it be true that $\mathcal F^{-1} M_{|\cdot |^\delta} \mathcal F$ leaves $L^2([-C,C])$ invariant, i.e. that $\mathcal F^{-1} M_{|\cdot |^\delta} \mathcal F \phi \in L^2([-C,C])$ for all $\phi \in L^2([-C,C])$?

Comment: what do you mean leaving invariant ? and if you write your operator as a convolution, you see that its image is no longer zero outside of $[-C,C]$, and that it is less  smooth than the function you applied it to

Comment: By invariant I mean that if I take a function $\phi \in L^2([-C,C])$ (considered as subspace of $L^2(\mathbb R))$ that $\mathcal F^{-1} M_{|\cdot |^\delta} \mathcal F \phi \in L^2([-C,C])$. With writing as convolution you mean writing $\mathcal F^{-1} M_f \mathcal F \phi = c \mathcal F^{-1} f * \phi$ with some constant c? But then $f$ needs to be some $L^2$ function, which is not the case if $f(x) = |x|^\delta$(?)